# cannot update wordpress from 3.4.2 to 3.5

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

I am trying to update wordpress from 3.4.2 to 3.5 . However, when I update, I get my old version 3.4.2 back. What could be causing this?

When I click on update it shows all the steps but in the final step it gives back the 3.4.2 screen and the version remains un updated.

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins in use? Try to clear/disable those if so. Or try to clear your browser's cache or view from another browser. There is no error at all? How many times have you managed to update?

Comment: I have tried it on several browsers and tried the updated 3 times already. There is no caching plugin installed. All my wordpress core folders wp-includes, wp-admin , wp-content have write permissions. However, the update goes until the last step and finally it gives me the 3.4.2 screen instead of 3.5

Comment: You might wish to uninstall WordPress and reinstall it. Be very careful if you choose to do this. Make a backup of everything. You'll want to save the wp-contents folder (especially the theme and upload), make note of the mysql username/password/path in wp-config.php. Install WP fresh and bring back in the wp-contents folder, using same database. Perhaps somehow your core files have become corrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the files aren't writable by WP for whatever reason.

Do a manual upgrade instead.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update